# Show that $o(\frac{a_n}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})+O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})=O(\frac{1}{na_n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Consider a sequence of real numbers $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}na_n=\infty$. Could you help me to show that $o(\frac{a_n}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})+O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})=O(\frac{1}{na_n})$? Any hint would be really appreciated.

> My attempt (wrong?) I'm not sure of the last step; moreover, if
>   correct, the steps below show that
>   $o(\frac{a_n}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})+O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})\subseteq
>  O(\frac{1}{na_n})$ and not
>    $o(\frac{a_n}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})+O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})=
>  O(\frac{1}{na_n})$.

(1) $o(\frac{a_n}{n})=o(\frac{a_n^2}{na_n})=\frac{1}{na_n}o(a_n^2)$.

(2) Since $a_n^2 \in o(1)$ and $o(a_n^2)\subseteq o(o(1))=o(1)$, $\frac{1}{na_n}o(a_n^2)\subseteq \frac{o(1)}{na_n}=o(\frac{1}{na_n})\subseteq O(\frac{1}{na_n})$

(3) Since $\frac{1}{n}\in o(1)$, $o(\frac{1}{n})\subseteq o(1)\subseteq O(1)$

(4) $O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})=\frac{1}{n}O(a_n^2)\underbrace{\subseteq }_{\frac{1}{n}=o(1)}o(1)O(a_n^2)=o(1)a_n^2 
O(1)\underbrace{\subseteq}_{a_n^2\in o(1)}o(1)o(1)O(1)=o(1)\subseteq O(1)$

(5) Hence, $o(\frac{a_n}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})+O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})\subseteq O(\frac{1}{na_n})+O(1)+O(1)=O(\frac{1}{a_nn})$ since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}na_n=\infty$.

Comment: Hint: Multiply $o(\frac{a_n}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})+O(\frac{a_n^2}{n})$ by $n a_n$. What's the result?

Comment: I have added an attempt to my question, but I have still doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is equivalent to proving that $$o (a_n^2) + o (a_n) + O (a_n^3) = O (1).$$ Since $a_n = o (1),$ the RHS will be $= o (1) = O (1)$.